# Cryptographic failure while signing winforms exe - "The Parameter is incorrect"

Tags: c#, winforms, compiler-errors, sign

Trying to "Sign the assembly" in Signing tab of my WinForms application using my Comodo Code Signing Cert but I keep getting the error:

```
Cryptographic failure while signing assembly 'C:\Projects\SomeApplication\obj\Debug\Application.exe' -- 'Error signing assembly -- The parameter is incorrect. '
```

1. I exported from IE the certificate into a PFX file with public and private keys.
2. I created the SNK file by running `sn -p <pfxFile> <snkFile>`

Looked through **SO** and found a bunch of things to try, such as adding a SGen section to the project but to no avail.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <SGenUseProxyTypes>false</SGenUseProxyTypes>
  <SGenPlatformTarget>$(Platform)</SGenPlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Instead of running the certificate through the command line, I added the certificate to the build. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

**Context:** 
VS2013
Excel VSTO AddIn

I had the same problem when trying to use Comodo's rfc3161 timestamp server:

http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161

When I used the authenticode server or left it blank, the project built successfully:

http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode

Answer (score 0):

The certificate you downloaded from Comodo must have the "Code Signing" Object Identifier (OID) "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3" in the Enhanced Key Usage (EKU) field. You may have purchased an SSL certificate by mistake.

Comment: I'm havind the same problem; I've verified that the OID is correct in my case.